# Efficient way to stop a loop after specific number of seconds

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a loop in C++ that I would like to run for a few seconds. Although the amount of work on every iteration is different, from a few microseconds to seconds, it is ok to stop between iterations. It is high-performance code so I would like to avoid calculating time difference on each iteration:

```
while (!status.has_value())
{
  // do something

  // this adds extra delays that I would like to avoid
  if (duration_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now() - started).count() >= limit)
    status = CompletedBy::duration;
}
```

What I'm thinking is maybe there is a way to schedule signal and then stop the loop when it happens instead of checking the time difference on every iteration.

BTW, the loop may exit before the signal.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Such features may be system-specific.

Comment: The scheduling way would be slower. The faster thing is to calculate the difference. If Windows, you can do this fast enough with GetTickCount().

Comment: Your best bet is to use hardware timestamp counts, which are quite predictable on most major hardware and can be easily translated into time intervals.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Could you elaborate? I dont see why the scheduling would be "slower".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - even better, use duration type for limit, and simply compare with it. But OP's problem is performance, not cleanness of the code.

Comment: Because it would require some inter-thread mechanism to be triggered and a checking of synchronization primitivies, far more slower than manually checking and breaking when the time has elapsed.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis are you sure you understand how signalling works in, say, Unix systems?

Comment: It is totally viable. I would lanch another thread and flip a volatole atomic variable after some sleeping. The worker thread would check the variable before each iteration.  Or indeed schedule a signal and flip a sig_atomic_t variable.

Comment: He hasn't specified it's unix.

Comment: Did you profile your code and find that `duration_cast<seconds>(system_clock::now() - started).count() >= limit)` is the bottleneck? Because this line shouldn't take longer than a microsecond.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis But he did mention signals.

Comment: Wait, you want to avoid ... integer subtraction on each iteration?  Or do you want to avoid getting the current time?

Comment: I recommend you benchmark your code and measure how long that line of code takes. Then see if it needs to be any faster and how much faster ideally.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, but in Java. The general idea is to use a separate thread to manage a sentinel value, making your loop look like...

```
okayToLoop = true;
// code to launch thread that will wait N milliseconds, and then negate okayToLoop
while((!status.hasValue()) AND (okayToLoop)) {
    // loop code
}
```

The "cautionary note" is that many sleep() functions for threads employ "sleep at least" semantics, so if it is really important to **only** sleep N milliseconds, you'll need to address that in your thread implementation. But, this avoids constantly checking the duration for each iteration of the loop.

Note that this will also allow the current iteration of the loop to finish, before the sentinel value is checked. I have also implemented this approach where the "control thread" actually interrupts the thread on which the loop is executing, interrupting the iteration. When I've done this, I've actually put the loop into a worker thread.

Comment: That would require every access to okayToLoop to cause a synchronization point, which would shut down a lot of compiler optimizations, which will probably hurt performance a LOT more than what OP is doing already.

Comment: Okay, I'll accept that the okayToLoop approach has it's issues and, as with most things, is a trade-off.

What about the interrupt-based approach? The interrupt itself may be expensive (I've never been in a scenario where execution was millisecond-critical), but this approach eliminates the synchronized access on okayToLoop (btw, the synchronization should only be necessary if there is a penalty for an extra iteration through the loop, no?).

Comment: The interupt approach is fine in Pure C. But in C++, it would require instruction-level zero-cost unwind tables, which I don't think any modern compiler provide. If you are willing to play the undefined behavior game and/or pinky-swear that only trivial types will be involved inside of the loop, you might be able to get away with it. Even then, the compiler would fully be within its right to break everything since you would be in UB land.

Answer (score -1):

Any form of inter-thread communication is going to be way slower than a simple query of a high performance clock.

Now, `steady_clock::now()` might be too slow in the loop.

Using OS specific APIs, bind your thread to have ridiculous priority and affinity for a specific CPU.  Or use rdtsc, after [taking into account everything that can go wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter).  Calculate what value you'd expect to get if (a) something went wrong, or (b) you have passed the time threshold.

When that happens, check `steady_clock::now()`, see if you are close enough to being done, and if so finish.  If not, calculate a new high performance clock target and loop again.

Comment: `system_clock` is the wrong idea anyway because it can be *changed*; you need at least `steady_clock`.

Comment: _Any form of inter-thread communication is going to be way slower_ - there are forms of inter-thread communication that look like `x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`. That is just a plain `mov` instruction on x86_64.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Relaxed memory ordering doesn't require you actually get the value before the sun turns into a red giant last I checked.  It basically states that if the value is set to 7 then 10, you won't read 10 then 7.  I suppose if you know you are on  AMD-64 and know it is implemented as a mov, the only possible problem is cache coherancy, and you know that the write operation will flush the other CPU cache's.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont True, but that still doesn't make your first sentence assertion correct though.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I don't consider code that doesn't actually communicate anything to be communication.  I mean, it *could* eventually communicate something, but in order to get it to actually communicate something you are going to have to do something else...  In any case, write up an answer!  Might be more useful to the OP.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I would write an answer if OP benchmarked his code. Also note, that Linux kernel utilizes RCU heavily where writers use `mov` instruction. You may like to let Linus Torvalds know that RCU is not communication and that may it take forever for the change to become observable by other threads.